# Is there a KPrototypes-like clustering technique allowing for caps on cluster sizes?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis

Is there  a KPrototypes clustering technique in which you cap the size of a cluster?

For example, in my current clusters, I get 4 clusters where one contains 50% of the sample population. I'm wondering if there is something that already exists that would allow me to cap any cluster to be no more 30% the sample and force the other data points beyond the 30% to be part of other clusters?

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question. I'll start by admitting that I don't know if there is an absolute correct answer to your question. I would surmise, that because clustering is unsupervised, you really don't have a lot of control over the outcome. You can certainly control the number of clusters, and some clustering techniques will pick the optimal number of clusters for you, so you don't have to make this decision, but your question is different, right. I'm interested to see what others have to say about this. In the meantime, check out the link below for a ton of info about clustering.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html